# Join columns by referencedColumnName that is not primary key - id

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am rookie in Symfony Doctrine and need some help with Join entities.

Normally Column are joins by primary key ID

```php
    /**
     * User
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="users")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MainBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
     * UniqueEntity("email", message="Account with email already exists.")
     */
    class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
    {
    /**
         * @var \MainBundle\Entity\PersonDetails
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MainBundle\Entity\Person")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_details_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
         * })
         */
    private $personDetails = null;
```

This is ok.

But problem is that I want to Join two columns in Relation OneToOne by id field in User Entity

```php
    /**
     * User
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="users")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MainBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
     * UniqueEntity("email", message="Account with email already exists.")
     */
    class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
    {
    /**
         * @var \MainBundle\Entity\PersonDetails
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MainBundle\Entity\Person")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=true)
             * })
             */
        private $personDetails = null;
```

When I try to join columns on this way I get error

> Missing value for primary key id on MainBundle\Entity\PersonDetails

Is it possible to index other field than id or what I trying to do is impossible?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please fix the code in your question with correct indentation, it's hardly readable. What is the diference between **id field** and **primary id** in your `User` entity?  There seem to be properties missing (i.e. the property with `@ORM\Id()`) ... which are needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the column-name and the field-name that shall be referenced in your `@JoinColumn` declaration.

```
@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
```

This way Doctrine looks for a field/property named `user_id` on your `User` entity. I guess you want the column in the join-table to be named `user_id` and the entries being `id`'s of the `User` entity.

**UserDetail**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserDetail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *   targetEntity="User",
     *   inversedBy="details"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *   name="user_id",
     *   referencedColumnName="id"
     * )
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    { 
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /** @ORM\Column() */
    protected $key;

    /** @ORM\Column() */
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($key, $value)
    {
       $this->key = $key;
       $this->value = $value;
    }
```

**User**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="UserDetail",
     *   mappedBy="user", 
     *   cascade={
     *     "persist",
     *     "remove",
     *     "merge"
     *   },
     *   orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    protected $details;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->details = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addDetail(UserDetail $detail)
    {
        $detail->setUser($this);
        $this->details->add($detail);

        return $this;
    }
```

Now if you add a detail to your `User` like this and persist/flush afterwards:

```
$user->addDetail(new UserDetail('Height', '173cm'));
```

This will result in a join-colum in the `user_detail` table that looks like this:

```
| key           | value     | user_id |
|---------------|-----------|---------|
| Height        | 173cm     | 1       |
```

Answer (score 2):

Citing [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys):

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys.
> Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading
> proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine
> can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this
> settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

I had the same problem, I solved it by performing the mapping only to fields that are primary keys. If I needed to get the related entities by other fields, I implemented methods in the [Entity repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository).